# Web scraping BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a jupyter notebook script extracting text from a [webpage](http://arhiva.zdravlje.gov.rs/showelement.php?id=8464) and putting it into a dataframe. I need to get each line of the `("div",{"align":"justify"})` tag: the first line is hospital name, second is address, third is phone number, and fourth is url.

I am iterating over the `<strong>` element, but this hasn't worked. With the code below I have only managed to get the first name plus the weird spaces after it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

myurl = 'http://arhiva.zdravlje.gov.rs/showelement.php?id=8464'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(myurl)

#put content into a variable and close connection
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html')

divTag = page_soup.findAll("div",{"align":"justify"})

#iterate over 'strong' tag and put into list
mylist = []
for tag in divTag:   
   # print(tag.text)
    hospital_name = tag.strong.get_text()
    mylist.append(str(hospital_name))
    print(hospital_name)

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':mylist})
```

This is what `mylist` looks like:

```
['Северно Бачки округ',
 'Дом здравља Бачка Топола \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 ',
 'Дом здравља Алибунар']
```

Here's a sample of the `<div align="justify">` section of the `page_soup` variable (note the spaces):

```
<div align="justify"><div align="center"><hr/><strong>Северно Бачки округ<br/></strong><hr/><strong><br/></strong></div></div><div align="justify"><strong>Дом здравља Бачка Топола                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </strong><br/>Адреса: Светог Стефана 1, Бачка Топола<br/>Број телефона: 024/715-425<br/>Званична интернет презентација: <a href="http://www.dzbt.co.rs/">www.dzbt.co.rs</a><br/><br/><strong>Дом здравља Мали Иђош</strong><br/>Адреса: Занатлијска 1, 24321 Мали Иђош<br/>Број телефона: 024/730-236<br/>Званична интернет презентација: <a href="http://www.dzmi.rs/">www.dzmi.rs<br/></a><br/><strong>Дом здравља Суботица</strong><br/>Адреса: Петефи Шандора 7, 24000 Суботица<br/>Број телефона: 024/600735<br/>Званична интернет презентација: <a href="http://domzdravlja.org.rs/">domzdravlja.org.rs<br/></a><br/><strong>Општа Болница Суботица</strong><br/>Адреса: Изворска 3, 24000 Суботица<
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: <br> is a void element that's why it doesn't have the closing tag.

Comment: Thanks I rephrased the question

Answer (score 0):

Parsing this kind of documents is quite hard (it seems that the document is not machine generated, but generated by hand).

You can try this example to get all addresses to DataFrane:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup, Tag, Comment
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

myurl = 'http://arhiva.zdravlje.gov.rs/showelement.php?id=8464'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(myurl)

#put content into a variable and close connection
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

all_strongs = page_soup.select('div[align="justify"] > strong:not(:contains("нема"))')
data = []
for s in all_strongs:
    out = ''
    n = s.next_sibling
    while n:
        if isinstance(n, Tag) and n.name == 'strong' and n in all_strongs:
            break
        if isinstance(n, Tag) and n.name == 'div' and 'align' in n.attrs and n['align'] == 'center':
            n = n.next_sibling
            continue
        if not isinstance(n, Comment):
            out += str(n)
        n = n.next_sibling

    data.append( BeautifulSoup(out, 'html.parser').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n') )

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': data})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                  Text
0    Адреса: Светог Стефана 1, Бачка Топола\nБрој т...
1    Адреса: Занатлијска 1, 24321 Мали Иђош\nБрој т...
2    Адреса: Петефи Шандора 7, 24000 Суботица\nБрој...
3    Адреса: Изворска 3, 24000 Суботица\nБрој телеф...
4    Адреса: Матије Гупца 26, 24000 Суботица\nБрој ...
..                                                 ...
340  Адреса: Требевићка 16, 11030 Београд\nБрој тел...
341  Адреса: др Суботића 5, 11000 Београд\nБрој тел...
342  Адреса: Војводе Степе 458, 11152 Београд\nБрој...
343  Адреса: Стари град Булевар деспота Стефана 54а...
344  Адреса: 38252 Шилово\nБрој телефона:\nЗванична...

[345 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you, thats already much better. Now I have to figure out how to parse the individual lines

Comment: @KimberlyClemons You can do `print( BeautifulSoup(out, 'html.parser').get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|') )`. But as I said, the document is not very well structured, so you have to do additional postprocessing of data.

Comment: Can you also please help me get the names of each hospital? The ones in bold. If I take out > strong:not(:contains("нема"))') it only gets the names of the ones before the spaces.